# how to plot mean proportion of binary data?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe in R that has a similar structure to the toy dataframe below. Subjects are presented with some objects and respond TRUE or FALSE to the below categories.

```
subject     object      animal     pet      furry

1           A           TRUE       TRUE     FALSE
1           B           TRUE       TRUE     TRUE
1           C           TRUE       FALSE    TRUE
1           D           TRUE       FALSE    FALSE
2           A           TRUE       TRUE     FALSE
2           B           FALSE      FALSE    FALSE
3           A           TRUE       TRUE     FALSE
3           B           FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
3           C           TRUE       TRUE     TRUE
...         ...         ...        ...      ...
```

If an object was labeled as animal = TRUE, pet = TRUE, and furry = TRUE, then the object is, for example, a lizard. Or FALSE-FALSE-FALSE is a plant. It doesn't really matter what the object actually is, but that there are 8 possible combinations like the below:

```
TRUE-TRUE-TRUE
TRUE-TRUE-FALSE
TRUE-FALSE-FALSE
FALSE-FALSE-FALSE
TRUE-FALSE-TRUE
FALSE-FALSE-TRUE
FALSE-TRUE-TRUE
FALSE-TRUE-FALSE
```

I am attempting to find the *mean proportion of combinations* by subject and represent this in a stacked bar plot (in ggplot2). But I don't know how to do this with my binary data. Overall, what I'm trying to represent, is the mean proportion of how subjects labeled these objects. For example, subject_1 contained 60% `TRUE-TRUE-FALSE`, 20% `FALSE-TRUE-FALSE`, 20% `TRUE-TRUE-TRUE`, and 0% for rest of the categories.

Apologies if anything is unclear. Happy to edit things with feedback.

Comment: can you show the expected output.  Is it a concatenated string?

Comment: @akrun — thanks for your question. I'm actually not sure how binary data like this is transformed, but I'm hoping for a plot that looks like this https://sebastiansauer.github.io/images/2017-01-20/unnamed-chunk-1-1.png. The groups (e.g., 0, 1, etc) would instead be TRUE-TRUE-TRUE, TRUE-TRUE-FALSE, etc. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your data ready for use with `ggplot2::geom_bar()` you will probably want to reorganize you data so that there is a column for the subject, a column indicating the type of T/F combination (`combo_str` below), and another column with proportion of times a particular combination occurs for that given subject (`prop` below):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# re-creating your data example:
df <- data.frame(subject = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 3)),
                 object = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C"),
                 animal = c(rep(T, 5), F, T, F, T),
                 pet = c(T, T, F, F, T, F, rep(T,3)),
                 furry = c(F, T, T, rep(F, 5), T))

# by subject, summarize the proportion of these T/F combinations 
df <- df %>%
  # create a unique identifier for each combination (e.g. "TRUE-TRUE-FALSE")
  mutate(combo_str = paste(animal, pet, furry, sep = "-"))%>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  # count the number of times this subject occurs in df:
  mutate(n_objects = n()) %>% 
  group_by(subject, combo_str) %>%
  # prop of times each combo type occurs for a given subject:
  summarize(prop = n()/n_objects)
```

You can then plot your data with `geom_bar()` like @DanielJachetta showed:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(fill = combo_str, y = prop, x = subject))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

Answer (score 0):

For your plot you want, you will want this code, but modified for your data

```
 # library
library(ggplot2)
 
# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
 
# Stacked + percent
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")
```

[code came from here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html)

Comment: thank you! can you please explain how I should adapt my binary data? I'm not quite understanding yet.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. You have all these TRUE and FALSE, but only 8 different outcomes, why not just visualize the distribution of outcomes. Ex: 3 dogs, 8 lizards, 2 fishes, etc? Then it can just be a histogram